# Search closest candidates using a given location

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, geolocation

I have a list of candidates with their suburb, state and postcode in our database. Upon request we will find the nearest suburb according to a suburb our client gave us.

The problem is the current algorithm only calculates airline distance (Means the linear distance between two points). In real life we would have river or mountain. E.g.

[image: Real Life example of calculate distance]

The client is at point A. B, C is in our database. The airline distance between A and B is shorter but in real life you have to go cross the bridge to get to B. So C is the shortest candidate in this example.

I am wondering if this can be done with third party api (Google Map?). Please bear in mind that we have more than 3000 candidates in our database so loop through each of them and compare with client location is not practical.

Comment: Maybe you can look for direction between two places and get all possible transport (Metro, Bus, Car, Airline). Google Map can provide estimated time then select lowest time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but at the moment we only care about driving distance as they are all on site technicians with vans or ute.

Comment: For your second question, searching for suitable candidate in all of the candidate will not be efficient. I would suggest building a data structure that stores nearby location to the given location. Or use google map and query for given range like (within 50 miles) and check if returned location is one of the location in your database

Comment: IF you want driving distance then it's okay. You can still use google maps to get estimated time

Answer (score 0):

This - [Google Maps Distance API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) provides what you want, driving (or any other modes) distance between locations.

But the interesting problem is that there are 3000 points which have to be compared to a particular destination. A possible solution would be to use a combination of your current algorithm and google maps api's multiple origin feature. (
the google maps distance API allows multiple origins/destinations to be specified.)

So:
- use current algorithm to find the closest 10 or 30 suburbs by airline distance.
- send all those locations as the origin parameter in one query to the google maps API.

The api would return the distance between the destination and all the origins. This may not give the correct result 100% of the time *if* the closest suburb is NOT in the 10or 20 closest suburbs we calculated using the airline distance algo. But this should be very unlikely....

Note:

Please see the exact usage limits for google maps API. Both for number of requests per day and number of origin points that you can give. Its all documented though

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API provide a directions service that can be accessed through a  `google.maps.DirectionsService` object ([here is the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsService)).

When sending a request to a directions service you can specify a travel mode (one of bicycling, driving, transit, walking), so this will take care of the additional distance with respect to airline distance.

Here's a demo ([Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/fLogwsff/2/)). Hope it helps.

```js
function initMap() {
  var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.2750, 1.0870),
    pointC = new google.maps.LatLng(50.7700, 0.28),
    pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5379, 0.7138),
    airDistAB = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pointA, pointB),
    airDistAC = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pointA, pointC),
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: pointA,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map
    }),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      title: "point A",
      label: "A",
      map: map
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointB,
      title: "point B",
      label: "B",
      map: map
    }),
    markerC = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointC,
      title: "point C",
      label: "C",
      map: map
    }),
    outputAtoB = document.getElementById('a2b'),
    outputAtoC = document.getElementById('a2c');
  // calculate routes
  responseAB = calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB, outputAtoB, airDistAB, true);
  responseAC = calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointC, outputAtoC, airDistAC, false);
  // click on marker B to get route from A to B
  markerB.addListener('click', function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB, outputAtoB, airDistAB, true);
  });
  markerC.addListener('click', function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointC, outputAtoC, airDistAC, true);
  });
  document.getElementById('mode').addEventListener('change', function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB, outputAtoB, airDistAB, true);
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointC, outputAtoC, airDistAC, false);
  });

}



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, point1, point2, outputTxt, airDist, display) {
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
  directionsService.route({
    origin: point1,
    destination: point2,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      if (display) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
      outputTxt.innerHTML = "~" + Math.round(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) + " Km" + " (air: ~" + Math.round(airDist / 1000) + "Km)";
      return response;
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        width: 60%;
        float: left;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: float top;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #678;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #123;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      #output {
        padding: 6px;
        width: 38%;
        float: right;
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>

<div id="floating-panel"> <b>Mode of Travel: </b>

  <select id="mode">
    <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
    <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
    <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
    <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="out<put">
  <h3>Distances</h3>
  <b> A to B: </b><span id="a2b"></span>
  <p> <b> A to C: </b><span id="a2c"></span>

</div>
```